# Stopwatch in react and useInterval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setinterval, use-state

I am trying to create a stop watch using react and set interval but do not understand why count variable is always 0 is it being reset to default state. I thought since state takes some time to update hence count was always 0 but even if i increase the set interval timer it shows the same value.

Through i am trying to understand how react hooks work if someone can shed some light on functioning of hooks or redirect me to necessary links please do so

code is working in case i replace setCount(count+1) to setCount(prevCount=>prevCount+1) also you need to declare intervalId outside of app function

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  let intervalId = -1;

  const increment = () => {
    console.log(count);
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const handleStart = () => {
    if (intervalId === -1)
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        // console.log("called");
        increment();
      }, 1000);
  };

  const handleStop = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    setCount(0);
  };

  const handlePause = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  };

  const handleResume = () => {
    handleStart();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="counter">{count}</div>
      <button onClick={handleStart} className="counter">
        start
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleStop} className="counter">
        stop
      </button>
      <button onClick={handlePause} className="counter">
        pause
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleResume} className="counter">
        resume
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means a React expert, but I watched this [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dpw9EHDh2bM) before and found it very enlightening, and I recommend you watch it too.

I also recommend you watch the first part, but the timestamp I linked is more relevant to your question.

Now in the official react docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), they say:

> If the new state is computed using the previous state, you can pass a function to setState. The function will receive the previous value, and return an updated value.

So, as you noticed with `prevCount`, it works when you do it that.

In this [blog post](https://sebhastian.com/setinterval-react/), the writer explains that:

> if you increment the count value as follows `setCount(count + 1)`
> The the count will stuck at 0 + 1 = 1 because the variable `count` value when `setInterval()` is called is 0.

So we know that we need the previous state. If you follow the blog post, he does set up a working counter.

The way the code is right now will create an interval for each click since the `intervalID` gets set to `-1` with each update. So, similar to the blogpost, we can have the interval ID as a state. Here's your stopwatch using that approach:

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-darkness-978nqr?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [intervalID, setIntervalID] = useState(0);

  const handleStart = () => {
    if (!intervalID) {
      let interval = setInterval(() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1), 1000);
      setIntervalID(interval)
    }
  };

  const handlePause = () => {
    if (intervalID){
      clearInterval(intervalID)
      setIntervalID(0)
    }
  };

  const handleStop = () => {
    handlePause();
    setCount(0)
  };

  const handleResume = () => {
    handleStart();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="counter">{count}</div>
      <button onClick={handleStart} className="counter">
        start
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleStop} className="counter">
        stop
      </button>
      <button onClick={handlePause} className="counter">
        pause
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleResume} className="counter">
        resume
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But this way, we have no way to clear the interval after unmounting the component. So we'll need `useEffect()`. And since we're using `useEffect()`, ([check why here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)). And now, instead of saving our intervalID as the state, we can instead have an `isRunning` state and have `useEffect` create or clear the interval every time `isRunning` changes. So now all our handlers have to do is `setIsRunning` and `useEffect` will handle the rest.

So the code will look like this:

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-darkness-978nqr?file=/src/App.js:0-1174)

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(0);

  useEffect(()=> {
    let intervalId;
    if (isRunning) {
      intervalId = setInterval(() => setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1), 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalId)
    }
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId) // Clear after unmounting
  }, [isRunning])


  const handleStart = () => {
    setIsRunning(true);
  };

  const handleStop = () => {
    setIsRunning(false);
    setCount(0)
  };

  const handlePause = () => {
    setIsRunning(false);
  };

  const handleResume = () => {
    handleStart();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="counter">{count}</div>
      <button onClick={handleStart} className="counter">
        start
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleStop} className="counter">
        stop
      </button>
      <button onClick={handlePause} className="counter">
        pause
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleResume} className="counter">
        resume
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I really recommend you watch the talk I linked in the beginning. I'm sure you'll find it very helpful in terms of using hooks and some of the issues you can face and how to fix them.